# Select element has selected value -1

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Select element has selected value 4 (for example), I send form data to the server. The controller return partial view.

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var objSel = document.getElementById("IDVacationApplicationType");
            checkVacationType(objSel);
            $("select#IDVacationApplicationType").change(function () {
                checkVacationType(this);
            });

        });
        function checkVacationType(elem) {
            var item = $(elem).val();
            alert(item);
        }
 </script>
```

html:

```
<div class="form-position">
     <div class="form-label">
          @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VacationApplicationTypes)
     </div>
     <div class="form-value">
          @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IDVacationApplicationType, Model.VacationApplicationTypes)
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VacationApplicationTypes)
     </div>
</div>
```

**alert shows -1.**  **After that form has select element with selected value = 4. How can I get this 4?**

[image]

**Answer:  I had two the same ID in the page.**

Comment: can you share the generated html instead of the server template

Comment: @ArunPJohny
 `<select id="IDVacationApplicationType">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two the same ID in the page.
I need add class to the element:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IDVacationApplicationType, Model.VacationApplicationTypes, new { @class = "IDVacationApplicationType" })

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var objSel = $(".IDVacationApplicationType");

        checkVacationType(objSel);
        $(".IDVacationApplicationType").change(function () {
            checkVacationType(this);
        });

    });
    function checkVacationType(elem) {
        var item = $(elem).val();
        alert(item);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
 $('#IDVacationApplicationType').find(":selected").val();
```

So change your function as `checkVacationType` as

```
function checkVacationType(elem) {
    var item = $(elem).find(":selected").val();
    alert(item);
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qMmRn/1)

Comment: Thank you=) I had two the same ID in the page.